# Python get the file that uses import

Tags: python, import, python-import

This may confuse you but here is what I am trying to say:

so file1.py imports file2.py

```
import file2
```

then file2.py gets the name of the file that imported it self (means get file1.py because it imported file2.py). Is it possible to do that? If so please tell me

Comment: You can get the call stack (where it is called from) but not which module has imported it, since there can be many.

Comment: Kluas that is what I'm trying to saying can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: A module can be imported by *many* other modules, and it can be imported multiple times but is actually *run* only once. While it would in principle be possible to get the *first* and *all* modules importing another, it will involve looking into dark places of the interpreter. Are you absolutely sure this the only appropriate approach for the actual problem you need to solve?

Comment: MisterMiyagi yes this would solve my problem

Comment: Have look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html ! `print_stack()` and `extract_stack()` should be what you a looking for.

Comment: It's complicated though

Comment: Allow me to ask, *why*? Why should `file2` care what imported it? What problem *exactly* are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Because I need to get a function from file1 into file2, I want to make a syntax where if you imported file2 and created a function that fits in the name that uses in file2, file2's function will be replace with the function that you created function

Comment: That sounds more like file2 should be a *class*, which receives the function on initialisation or via inheritance. Alternatively, file2 could offer a function to register the missing piece or just be assigned the function - after all, the importing module has to be aware of the mechanism anyway.